# AudioContext cross domain blocking in iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, web-audio-api

Though I only play audio in response to clicks, I initialize the AudioContext and buffers and such when the script loads.

In mobile Chrome 57.0.2987.132 the console shows the following warning when loaded from an iframe:

> An AudioContext in a cross origin iframe must be created or resumed
>   from a user gesture to enable audio output.

For audio to work I recreate the AudioContext on first click.  Is there a way to simply activate the existing AudioContext on the first click?  Also can I detect whether the audio is currently blocked?

References:

- [Chromium issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=614115)
- [Chromium mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/51WbTwn0M_Y/VZuwn8-VAAAJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AudioContext.state will tell you if it's "running" or "suspended".  If it's "suspended", call AudioContext.resume() from inside a user gesture, and it should start it up for you (without having to recreate state).